# Filtering dropdown menu's with ajax and PHP

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter, jquery

I have a CodeIgniter MVC application.

I have a model called city that has a method:

```
<?php
class Cities_model extends Model{    

function Cities_model(){
    parent::Model();
}

function get_cities($id = null){
    $this->db->select('id, city_name');

    if($id != NULL){
        $this->db->where('country_id', $id);
    }

    $query = $this->db->get('cities');

    $cities = array();

    if($query->result()){
        foreach ($query->result() as $city) {
            $cities[$city->id] = $city->city_name;
        }
        return $cities;
    }else{
        return FALSE;
    }  
}
...
```

Controller:

```
function Post(){
    $this->load->helper('form');
    $this->load->model('cities_model');
    $this->load->model('country_model');
    $this->load->model('field_model');

    $data['cities'] = $this->cities_model->get_cities();//optional $id parameter 
    $data['countries'] = $this->country_model->get_countries();

    $data['fields'] = $this->field_model->get_fields(); //subject field

    $this->load->view('post_view',$data);
}
```

This method is used to fill the contents of a dropdown list. I have a similar model for countries, which also has a dropdown.

You can see that the get_cities method is set up to accept a country_id. This would be used to filter the results if a country was selected.

My question is I need help calling this method using Ajax (preferably jQuery). I'm new to ajax and have never done anything like this before.

Any help most appreciated!

Billy

**UPDATE**

I've added jquery library and have created method in my controller:

```
function get_cities($country){
    header('Content-Type: application/x-json; charset=utf-8');
    echo(json_encode(array($this->cities_model->get_cities($country))));
}
```

here is my javascript on my view:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  $(document).ready(function(){

  $('#country').change(function(){
    var country_id = $('#country').val();  // here we are taking country id of the selected one.
    $.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>home/get_cities/"+country_id,
     data: ({country : country_id}),
     success: function(cities){
       $.each(cities,function(i,city)
       {
          var opt = $('<option />');
          opt.val(city.value);
          opt.text(city.text);
          $('#cities').append(opt);
       });
    }

  });

  });
  });
```

This is the json reply:

```
[{"2":"Accra"}]
```

So it is successfully retriving the correct data. the only problem is it's adding blank values/text to the drop down. and each time I change the city the data is being added on, so I guess i'd have to clear the dropdown first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

extending Alpesh's answer:

you should have a controller's function which return cities filtered by country:

```
/controller/get_cities/<country>
```

i'm assuming that your controller's function will return a json object, you can obtain it by doing:

```
function get_cities($country)
{
   header('Content-Type: application/x-json; charset=utf-8');
   echo(json_encode(array($this->cities_model->get_cities($country))));
}
```

then on the view you'll have 2 select boxes:

1. one filled up with the contries
2. one empty and to be filled up with the cities retrived via ajax

now, you have to write something like Alpesh did in order to retrive the cities of the selected country; URL will be

```
url: '/controller/get_cities/'+country_id
```

while the success function would be something like

```
success: function(cities)
{
   $('#cities').empty();
   $.each(cities,function(i,city)
   {
      var opt = $('<option />');
      opt.val(city.value);
      opt.text(city.text);
      $('#cities').append(opt);
   });
}
```

**UPDATE**
in your ajax success function you are dealing with a json objects, infact you are doing this:

```
opt.val(city.value);
opt.text(city.text);
```

where city is a json object and value and text are its properties.

when you generate the json via php you have to respect what you use in jquery so your model should return an array like this:

```
array
(
   array("value"=>"2","text"=>"Accra"),
   array("value"=>"3","text"=>"Kumasi"),
   ....
);
```

the json_encode that array and it should work. Maybe you don't need to wrap the model call into an array but i'm not sure depens on how you return the array

```
echo(json_encode(array($this->cities_model->get_cities($country))));
```

or

```
echo(json_encode($this->cities_model->get_cities($country)));
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. I'm not sure whether I am doing it right. I've updated my question with my new code

Comment: also, the "i" in function(i, city) is never used

Comment: oh yes, there is a mistake: in your ajax call there is a duplicate country_id info: just drop the 'data: ({country : country_id}),' you are already sending the country_id via url. the variable 'i' is used to assign the number of element being processed (0,1,2...) it could be helpfull in case of debugging. I'm updating my answer

Comment: ok I ended up using opt.val(i) and opt.text(city). I think I was just confused before. I used $("select[id$=cities] > option").remove(); to clear the list on option change

Comment: to solve that problem just add this line to your ajax success function (before $.each()...): $('#cities').empty(); this will remove any html or text from your select box. doc: http://api.jquery.com/empty

Answer (score 1):

You can do it this way by jquery -

lets say you have 'country' as an id for the select for country -

then on change of country you can bring it's specific cities as follows -

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $('#country').change(function(){
    var country_id = $('#country').val();  // here we are taking country id of the selected one.
    $.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: "the url you want to call",
     data: ({id : country_id}),
     success: function(cities){
     //populate the options of your cities dropdown here.
     }
  });

  });
```

});

you can refer detailed documentation here -

[JQuery](http://docs.jquery.com/Main_Page)

[Ajax API](http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/)

[Ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)